# How does google move the search box to the top while typing?

Tags: ajax, search

Go to [google](http://google.com) type something and it will relocate the search box to the top, and load a results page without hitting search or enter.  The results page is black at first then as typing continues it loads results. I'm assuming this uses ajax, but does it load a new html page or somehow change the home page?

HTML:

```
   <div id="top_panel" class="main fluid">
        <nav id="topNav" class="fluid">
            <ul class="fluid fluidList navSystem">
                <li class="fluid navItem web"><a href="index.html" class="web">Web</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem photos"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- END .navSystem -->
        </nav> <!-- END #topNav -->
    </div> <!-- END #top_panel -->
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
function keypress() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("top_panel").removeClass("main").addClass("results");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Comment: educated guess: it simply moves the box (instead of drop/re-add) as to not lose focus. then, the new contents are brought it using AJAX (coupled with some UI styling).

Comment: I added html and ajax to change the class so I can change the css, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I got the onkeypress to change the class and move the object, but if you look at chitt-chat.com you can see that as you continue typing it keeps changing the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.  So the original problem was that I couldn't figure out how google moved their search box.  I thought it had some ajax involved.  I figured out that you can do it just with JS.  All I did was change the class of the top_panel div that contains the header and search.  With css I changed styles depending on the class.  This moved the search box nicely to where I wanted it, but there was still a problem.  When the user typed a second letter it would change the class back to the original and move the box.  The box would keep going back and forth as the user typed.  To fix this I added a simple if statement to the JS.

HTML:

```
   <div id="top_panel" class="main fluid">
        <nav id="topNav" class="fluid">
            <ul class="fluid fluidList navSystem">.......</ul> <!-- END .navSystem -->
        </nav> <!-- END #topNav -->

        <header id="header" class="fluid">
            <div id="innerHead" class="fluid">
                <div id="logo" class="">
                <img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Chitt Chat"/>
              </div> <!-- END #logo -->
                <div id="search" class="">
                <form class="form-wrapper cf">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search here..." id="field" required>
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                </div> <!-- END #search -->
            </div> <!-- END #innerHead -->
         </header><!-- END #header -->
    </div> <!-- END #top_panel -->
```

JS:

```
    <script>
$('#field').on('keypress', function () {
    if ($('#top_panel').hasClass('main')) {
        $('#top_panel').toggleClass('main results');
    }
});
</script>
```